# R type conversion expression() function()

Tags: r, function, expression, type-conversion

I've been trying to write a program in R that implements Newton's method.  I've been mostly successful, but there are two little snags that have been bothering me.  Here's my code:

```
Newton<-function(f,f.,guess){
    #f <- readline(prompt="Function? ")
    #f. <- readline(prompt="Derivative? ")
    #guess <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Guess? "))
    a <- rep(NA, length=1000)
    a[1] <- guess
    a[2] <- a[1] - f(a[1]) / f.(a[1])
    for(i in 2:length(a)){
        if(a[i] == a[i-1]){
           break
        } 
        else{
           a[i+1] <- a[i] - f(a[i]) / f.(a[i])
        }
    }   
    a <- a[complete.cases(a)]
    return(a)
}
```

1. I can't get R to recognize the functions `f` and `f.` if I try using `readline()` to prompt for user input.  I get the error "Error in Newton() : could not find function "f.""  However, if I comment out the readlines (as above), define `f` and `f.` beforehand, then everything works fine.
2. I've been trying to make R calculate the derivative of a function.  The problem is that the class object with which R can take symbolic derivatives is `expression()`, but I want to take the derivative of a `function()` and have it give me a `function()`.  In short, I'm having trouble with type conversion between `expression()` and `function()`.

I have an ugly but effective solution for going from `function()` to `expression()`.  Given a function f, `D(body(f)[[2]],"x")` will give the derivative of `f`.  However, this output is an `expression()`, and I haven't been able to turn it back into a `function()`.  Do I need to use `eval()` or something?  I've tried subsetting, but to no avail.  For instance:

```
g <- expression(sin(x))
g[[1]]
sin(x)
f <- function(x){g[[1]]}
f(0)
sin(x)
```

when what I want is f(0) = 0 since sin(0) = 0.

EDIT:  Thanks all!  Here's my new code:

```
Newton<-function(f,f.,guess){
    g<-readline(prompt="Function? ")
    g<-parse(text=g)
    g.<-D(g,"x")
    f<-function(x){eval(g[[1]])}
    f.<-function(x){eval(g.)}
    guess<-as.numeric(readline(prompt="Guess? "))
    a<-rep(NA, length=1000)
    a[1]<-guess
    a[2]<-a[1]-f(a[1])/f.(a[1])
    for(i in 2:length(a)){
        if(a[i]==a[i-1]){break
        }else{
        a[i+1]<-a[i]-f(a[i])/f.(a[i])
        }
    }   
a<-a[complete.cases(a)]
#a<-a[1:(length(a)-1)]
return(a)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. This first problem arises because `readline` reads in a text string, whereas what you need is an expression. You can use `parse()` to convert the text string to an expression:

   ```
   f <-readline(prompt="Function? ")
   sin(x)
   f
   # [1] "sin(x)"

   f <- parse(text = f)
   f
   # expression(sin(x))

   g <- D(f, "x")
   g
   # cos(x)
   ```
2. To pass in values for the arguments in the function call in the expression (whew!), you can `eval()` it in an environment containing the supplied values. Nicely, R will allow you to supply those values in a list supplied to the `envir=` argument of `eval()`:

   ```
   > eval(f, envir=list(x=0))
   # [1] 0
   ```

Comment: Thank you!
Is there a better alternative to readline()?  I didn't know about parse(), though I had tried as.expression unsuccessfully.  Also, is there a better option for going from function() to expression() other than body()?

Comment: `readline()` is the right function for taking typed input from users, and there is no better way than `parse()` to convert text to expressions. Not sure what you mean by going from `function()` to `expression()`, though. Is `function()` a function call, or a function definition?

Comment: I mean things that are in the `function()` class, and which are specifically mathematical functions.  For example, say I have the function `f<-function(x){3x*sin(x/3) + 2*cos(4*x)}` and I want to find its derivative.  The only way I know to do this is to use `body()` to obtain an expression, and then use `D(body(f)[[2]],"x")`.

Comment: OK. There are a few problems here. (1) comparing `class(f)` and `class(body(f))` shows that `body(f)` is a function call, not a function. (That's OK of course, since for `D()` you really want an object of class `expression`, not `function`.) (2) Unless I'm mistaken you want to be taking the derivative of something that looks more like `body(f)` than `body(f)[[2]]`. (3) You probably want to use `as.expression` to do this: `D(as.expression(body(f)), "x")`. Does that get you closer to where you want to be?

Comment: I think the subsetting (i.e. using the [[2]]) is necessary, otherwise the curly brackets cause problems.  For instance: 
`> f<-function(x){3*x*sin(x/3) + 2*cos(4*x)}
> class(body(f))
[1] "{"
> class(f)
[1] "function"
> class(body(f))
[1] "{"
> class(body(f)[[2]])
[1] "call"`

And, trying out your example, I get an error:
`> D(as.expression(body(f)), "x")
Error in D(as.expression(body(f)), "x") : 
  Function '`{`' is not in the derivatives table`
I study math, so I apologize for not being too familiar with the terminology.

Comment: Got'cha. I had typed `f <- function(x) 3*x*sin(x/3) + 2*cos(4*x)` (i.e., without the brackets), for which `D(as.expression(body(f)), "x")` does work.

Comment: Haha, and today I learned that I don't need to surround the function's body with brackets.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Josh has answered your question

For part 2 you could have used

```
g <- expression( sin(x) )

g[[1]]
# sin(x)

f <- function(x){ eval( g[[1]] ) }

f(0)
# [1] 0
f(pi/6)
# [1] 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you!  One more wrinkle: what if I want to get rid of the expression variable (g in your example)?  Really, I'd like to do
     f <- expression(sin(x)) 
     f <- function(x){eval(f[[1]])}
but that creates a circular dependence since in 'eval(f[[1]])' the 'f[[1]]' isn't replaced by what's actuallly in f (namely 'sin(x)').

Comment: I am no longer clear what you are asking for.  Perhaps your are looking for  something like this which does not have  g: `f <- function(x){ eval( expression( sin(x) )[[1]] ) }; f(pi/6)` or perhaps something which is not a function `x <- pi/4 ; eval( expression (sin(x)))`

Comment: Exactly--I want to eliminate g.  I'd like to be able to extract the contents of g and then get rid of g.  Using my example:
    '> g<-expression(sin(x))
    > f<-function(x){eval(g[[1]])}
    > f
    function(x){eval(g[[1]])}'
When what I really want is 
       '> f
       function(x){sin(x)}'
In other words, I want to remove the dependence of f on g.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

BTW,  having recently written a toy which calculates fractal patterns based on root convergence of Newton's method  in the complex plane,  I can recommend you toss in some code like the following (where  the main function's argument list includes "func" and "varname" ).

```
func<- gsub(varname, 'zvar', func)
    funcderiv<- try( D(parse(text=func), 'zvar') )
    if(class(funcderiv) == 'try-error') stop("Can't calculate derivative")
```

If you're more cautious, you could include a an argument "funcderiv" , and wrap my code in

```
if(missing(funcderiv)){blah blah}
```

Ahh, why not: here's my complete function for all to use and enjoy:-)

```
# build Newton-Raphson fractal
#define: f(z)  the convergence per Newton's method is 
# zn+1 = zn - f(zn)/f'(zn)
#record which root each starting z0 converges to, 
# and to get even nicer coloring, record the number of iterations to get there.
# Inputs:
#   func: character string, including the variable. E.g., 'x+ 2*x^2' or 'sin(x)'
#   varname: character string indicating the variable name
#   zreal: vector(preferably) of Re(z)
#   zim: vector of Im(z)
#   rootprec: convergence precision for the NewtonRaphson algorithm
#   maxiter: safety switch, maximum iterations, after which throw an error
#
nrfrac<-function(func='z^5 - 1 ', varname = 'z', zreal= seq(-5,5,by=.1), zim, rootprec=1.0e-5, maxiter=1e4, drawplot=T, drawiterplot=F, ...) {
    zreal<-as.vector(zreal)
    if(missing(zim)) zim <- as.vector(zreal)
# precalculate F/F' 
    # check for differentiability (in R's capability)
    # and make sure to get the correct variable name into the function
    func<- gsub(varname, 'zvar', func)
    funcderiv<- try( D(parse(text=func), 'zvar') )
    if(class(funcderiv) == 'try-error') stop("Can't calculate derivative")  
# Interesting "feature" of deparse : default is to limit each string to 60 or64
# chars.  Need to avoid that here.  Doubt I'd ever see a derivative w/ more
# than 500 chars, the max allowed by deparse. To do it right, 
# need sum(nchar(funcderiv)) as width, and even then need to do some sort of
# paste(deparse(...),collapse='') to get a single string
    nrfunc <- paste(text='(',func,')/(',deparse(funcderiv, width=500),')', collapse='')
# first arg to outer()  will give rows
# Stupid Bug: I need to REVERSE zim to get proper axis orientation
    zstart<- outer(rev(zim*1i), zreal, "+")
    zindex <- 1:(length(zreal)*length(zim))
    zvec <- data.frame(zdata=as.vector(zstart), zindex=zindex,     itermap=rep(0,length(zindex)), badroot=rep(0,length(zindex)), rooterr=rep(0,length(zindex)) )

#initialize data.frame for zout.  
    zout=data.frame(zdata=rep(NA,length(zstart)), zindex=rep(NA,length(zindex)),     itermap=rep(0,length(zindex)), badroot=rep(0,length(zindex)), rooterr=rep(0,length(zindex)))
    # a value for rounding purposes later on; yes it works for  rootprec >1 
    logprec <-  -floor(log10(rootprec))
    newtparam <- function(zvar) {}
    body(newtparam)[2]  <- parse(text=paste('newz<-', nrfunc, collapse=''))
    body(newtparam)[3] <- parse(text=paste('return(invisible(newz))'))
    iter <- 1
    zold <- zvec  # save zvec so I can return original values
    zoutind <- 1 #initialize location to write solved values
    while (iter <= maxiter & length(zold$zdata)>0 ) {
        zold$rooterr <- newtparam(zold$zdata)
        zold$zdata <- zold$zdata - zold$rooterr
        rooterr <- abs(zold$rooterr)
        zold$badroot[!is.finite(rooterr)] <- 1
        zold$zdata[!is.finite(rooterr)] <- NA
# what if solvind = FFFFFFF? -- can't write 'nothing' to zout
        solvind <- (zold$badroot >0 | rooterr<rootprec)
            if( sum(solvind)>0 ) zout[zoutind:(zoutind-1+sum(solvind)),] <- zold[solvind,]
    #update zout index to next 'empty' row
        zoutind<-zoutind + sum(solvind)
# update the iter count for remaining elements:
        zold$itermap <- iter
# and reduce the size of the matrix being fed back to loop
        zold<-zold[!solvind,]
        iter <- iter +1
    # just wonder if a gc() call here would make any difference
# wow -- it sure does
        gc()
    }  # end of while
# Now, there may be some nonconverged values, so:
#  badroot[]  is set to 2  to distinguish from Inf/NaN locations
        if( zoutind < length(zindex) ) { # there are nonconverged values
#  fill the remaining rows, i.e. zout.index:length(zindex)
            zout[(zoutind:length(zindex)),] <- zold # all of it
            zold$badroot[] <- 2 # yes this is safe for length(badroot)==0
            zold$zdata[]<-NA #keeps nonconverged values from messing up results
            }
#  be sure to properly re-order everything...
    zout<-zout[order(zout$zindex),]
    zout$zdata <- complex(re=round(Re(zout$zdata),logprec), im=round(Im(zout$zdata),logprec) )
    rootvec <- factor(as.vector(zout$zdata), labels=c(1:length(unique(na.omit(as.vector(zout$zdata))))))
    #convert from character, too!
    rootIDmap<-matrix(as.numeric(rootvec), nr=length(zim))
# to colorize very simply:  
    if(drawplot) {
             colorvec<-rainbow(length(unique(as.vector(rootIDmap))))
        imagemat<-rootIDmap
        imagemat[,]<-colorvec[imagemat]  #now has color strings
        dev.new()
# all '...' arguments used to set up plot
        plot(range((zreal)),range((zim)), t='n',xlab='real',ylab='imaginary',... ) 
        rasterImage(imagemat, range(zreal)[1], range(zim)[1], range(zreal)[2], range(zim)[2], interp=F)     
        }

    outs <- list(rootIDmap=rootIDmap, zvec=zvec, zout=zout, nrfunc=nrfunc)
    return(invisible(outs))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your code.  I haven't read all the way through it yet, but I'm sure I can improve my program by emulating your code.