# Defining a new function calling another function by name in R

Tags: r, function

I define a new function with a function (by name) as argument, but the derivative doesn't work. What happen?. The code is

```
myfun = function(f, a){
          fx = function(x) f(x)
          print(fx(a)) # = f(a) OK
          fp = function(x) eval( D(expression(fx), "x") )
          fp(a) # = 1/2*sqrt(a) doesn't work!
        }
        myfun(sqrt, 4) 
      # console-------------------------------------------
       > myfun(sqrt, 4) # = 1/2*sqrt(4) = 1/4
       [1] 2
       [1] 0
```

> 

Comment: I don't think `D(expression(fx), "x")` will work in this case. This is no such variable called "x" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question in: [R type conversion expression() function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857042/r-type-conversion-expression-function).

I could modify my code in several ways:

```
  # 1. ----------------------------------- 
  myfun = function(f, a){
        g  = parse(text=f)     # f is string
        # fx = function(x){eval(g[[1]])}
        g. = D(g,"x")
        fp = function(x){eval(g.)}
        fp(a)
                        }
  myfun('sqrt(x)', 4) # 0.25

# 2. ----------------------------------- 
fa = function(x){sqrt(x)}   # with { }
fb = function(x) sqrt(x)    # without { }

my2fun = function(f, a){
          if(body(f)[[1]]== '{' ){ 
               g. = D(body(f)[[2]], "x")
          } else {
                   g. = D(as.expression(body(f)), "x")  
                 }
  fp = function(x){eval(g.)}
  fp(a)
}
my2fun(fa, 4) # 0.25

 # 3. And more general
fa = function(x){sqrt(x)}    # with { }
fb = function(x) sqrt(x)     # no { } 
lafun = function(f, a){
  # add { }
  if(body(f)[[1]]!= '{' ) body(f) = call("{", body(f))     
  g. = D(body(f)[[2]], "x")  
  fp = function(x){eval(g.)}
  print(f(a))
  print(fp(a))
}
lafun(fa, 4) 
lafun(fb, 4) 
# 0.25
# 0.25
```

I need this code because I'm working on numerical methods with R.